# How to get date from a certain year and ordinal day number in the year using luxon?

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

Is it possible to get date and month having year and ordinal day number of this year, using luxon?

As example provided year 2015 and 125th day. Is it possible to get date (number and month) from that data, using luxon?

Comment: Create an instance using https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromobject, and pass in `year` and `ordinal`. And then get month and day from that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others in the comments, you can simply create a `DateTime` instance using [`fromObject`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromobject) that:

> Create a DateTime from a JavaScript object with keys like 'year' and 'hour' with reasonable defaults.

then you can access to the properties you need (e.g. [`month`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimemonth) and [`day`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeday)).

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const dt = DateTime.fromObject({year: 2015, ordinal: 125});
console.log(dt.toISO());
console.log("Month: " + dt.month + " day: " + dt.day)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.3.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```